# error: has incomplete type|: within a nested class?

Tags: c++, nested-class, incomplete-type

I'm trying to declare an object of type `WRAPPED` that is within the class `WRAPPED` and the class `WRAPPED` is contained within another class called `WRAPPER`. I'm getting these compiler errors.

```
nested_class_incomplete_type.cpp|56|instantiated from 'WRAPPER<NODE>'|
nested_class_incomplete_type.cpp|62|instantiated from here|
nested_class_incomplete_type.cpp|36|error: 'WRAPPER<T>::WRAPPED::WRAP' has incomplete type|
nested_class_incomplete_type.cpp|33|error: declaration of 'class WRAPPER<NODE>::WRAPPED'|
```

I tried doing this too `WRAPPER::WRAPPED WRAP;` but that yields the same exact error. This normally would not be an issue if the `WRAPPED` class existed outside a class but for some reason it won't allow me to declare such a simple object. Feel free to enlighten me with the magical world of C++ compiler semantics and the god Stroustrup. Heres the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class NODE
{
        int data;

    public:

        NODE(){}
        ~NODE(){}
        NODE(int data)
        {
            this->data = data;
        }
        void print()
        {
            std::cout<<"data: "<<this->data<<std::endl;
        }
};
template <class T>
class WRAPPER
{
    public:

        static T GLOBAL_WRAPPER_TYPE;

    WRAPPER(){}
    ~WRAPPER(){}

        class WRAPPED
        {
            public:

            WRAPPER::WRAPPED WRAP;

            WRAPPED(){}
            ~WRAPPED(){}
            void set(T GLOBAL_WRAPPER_TYPE)
            {
                WRAPPER::GLOBAL_WRAPPER_TYPE = GLOBAL_WRAPPER_TYPE;
            }
            T& get()
            {
                return GLOBAL_WRAPPER_TYPE;
            }
            WRAPPED& operator=(const WRAPPED &INSIDE)
            {
                GLOBAL_WRAPPER_TYPE = INSIDE.GLOBAL_WRAPPER_TYPE;

                return *this;
            }
        };

        WRAPPED INSIDE;
};
template <class T>
T WRAPPER<T>::GLOBAL_WRAPPER_TYPE;
int main()
{
    WRAPPER<NODE> WRAPPING;
    WRAPPING.INSIDE.set(NODE(99));
    NODE temp = WRAPPING.INSIDE.get();
    temp.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your class contains an instance of itself. Which means in order to create a variable of that type you need to create a variable of that type, so you have to create a variable of that type... get it? ;)

Comment: I get it but I still can't see how to solve that.

Comment: You'll need to make it a reference or a pointer. You just can't contain yourself, that would make for infinitely big types.

Comment: So I just use `WRAPPER::WRAPPED* WRAP;`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially what you're trying to do is:

```
class A
{
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

(You can see that this produces the same error [here](http://ideone.com/cptjZC))

This is infinite recursion, you're defining a type using itself. Take a pointer instead, like so:

```
class A
{
    A* a;
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/DyOvNn) this compiles.